# Get get collision location on object

Tags: c#, frameworks

I try to make a Pong like video game using C#.

The basic game works well for me, but I want to divide the paddles into multiple zones.
Each zone should move the ball individual.

The problem is, that I don't really know how to get the correct zone of the paddle.
For example:

```
if (collision >= 50px){move ball in direction A}
else if (collision <= 100px && collision > 50px){move ball to direction B}
```

I tried using the Y value of Bounds, but it doesn't worked.

The next step I try is to get the ball location and the paddle location to calculate the zone.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `if (collision <= 50px)` if you want this to be the zone from 0-50px. You have the comparison the wrong way around (`>=` instead of `<=`).

Comment: @Longoon12000
Thanks!
It was a mistake made by me. In the real source code I use the comparison you submited.

Comment: I suggest that you copy and paste your real source code so that it's clear what you are doing and what the issue could be.

Comment: Also please explain what exactly it is that you need help with. Is it the if/then that you posted? Trying to figure out what values to compare? Or how to get where the collision occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it on my own.

I got the Y position of the paddle and the Y position of the ball.
Then I got the value I wanted by subtract the ball Y position by the paddle Y position.

Here is a snippet of the real source code:

```
//contact with right paddle
        else if (ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(paddle2.Bounds))
        {
            double paddle2_locationvar = paddle2.Top;
            paddle2_Bounds_text.Text = paddle2_locationvar.ToString() + " " + ball.Top.ToString();

            double ball_locationvar = ball.Top;

            double zonevar = ball_locationvar - paddle2_locationvar;

            paddle2_Bounds_text.Text = zonevar.ToString();

            timer5.Stop();

            //zones
            if (zonevar <= 12.571)
            {
                ballx = ballx * -1;
                bally = 6;
                timer5.Start();
            }
            else if (zonevar > 12.571 && zonevar <= 25.142)
            {
                ballx = ballx * -1;
                bally = 4;
                timer5.Start();
            }
            else if (zonevar > 25.142 && zonevar <= 37.713)
            {
                ballx = ballx * -1;
                bally = 2;
                timer5.Start();
            }
            else if (zonevar > 37.713 && zonevar <= 50.284)
            {
                ballx = ballx * -1;
                bally = 0;
                timer5.Start();
            }
            else if (zonevar > 50.284 && zonevar <= 62.855)
            {
                ballx = ballx * -1;
                bally = -2;
                timer5.Start();
            }
            else if (zonevar > 62.855 && zonevar <= 75.426)
            {
                ballx = ballx * -1;
                bally = -4;
                timer5.Start();
            }
            else if (zonevar > 75.426 && zonevar <= 88)
            {
                ballx = ballx * -1;
                bally = -6;
                timer5.Start();
            }
            else
                ballx = ballx * -1;
```

Thank you very much for your effort.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you are not taking care of all scenarios, for example
(collision >= 50px) can be true and (collision <= 100px && collision > 50px) can also be true when collision == 75

If you want to strictly determinate in which zone is your ball, you must use conditions more like this (I assume your variable collision is an integer)

```
if (collision >= int.MinValue && collision <= 50 ) // Move A
else if (collision > 50 && collision <= 100 ) // Move B
else if (collision > 100 && collision <= 150 ) // Move C
// Next areas...
else if (collision > 250 && collision <= int.MaxValue) // Move G
```

Just try to get only one condition with true at each moment, and you will get the correct area. I hope it helps.

Comment: I guess the example code I made for this post is with much more errors than the real code.
I alway got an else statement.